# WeakReference in AsyncTask got nullified despite the Activity is still shown

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I followed the pattern of using WeakReference in AsyncTask by assigning a weak reference in the constructor:

```
private final WeakReference<WeakClass> weakRef;

public WeakRefAsyncTask( @NotNull WeakClass _weakClassInstance ) {

    weakRef = new WeakReference<>( _weakClassInstance );
}

protected final @NonNull WeakClass getWeakOne() {

    WeakClass o = weakRef.get();

    if( o != null ) {

        return o;
    } else {

        throw new WeakRefIsNullException( getTaskDetailsDescription() );
    }
}
```

But now I get another issue - the weak reference now and again gets nullified even though the activity is still working (DoWeaklyAsyncTask being static inner descendant from WeakRefAsyncTask within AbstractPurchaseListActivity).

```
03-19 11:02:19.632 5184-5305/com.tsarsprocket.purchaselist.subscribe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
Process: com.tsarsprocket.purchaselist.subscribe, PID: 5184
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: com.tsarsprocket.DroidTools2.tools.WeakRefAsyncTask$WeakRefIsNullException: Weak reference is null. Task details:
Loading names already used in purchase list version, id=-1
    at com.tsarsprocket.DroidTools2.tools.WeakRefAsyncTask.getWeakOne(WeakRefAsyncTask.java:37)
    at com.tsarsprocket.purchaselist.core.AbstractPurchaseListActivity$DoWeaklyAsyncTask.doWeakInBackground(AbstractPurchaseListActivity.java:225)
    at com.tsarsprocket.DroidTools2.tools.WeakRefAsyncTask.doInBackground(WeakRefAsyncTask.java:118)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        ... 4 more
```

The problem is that the activity is still actual when the weakref is nullified and still needs the results of the acynctask. I suspect this is because of aggressive GC maybe. And the task cannot tell the activity that it failed because the weakref was the only link.

Is there any way to efficiently use weakrefs in asynctasks AND to prevent the asynctasks from failing due to weakref nullification please?

Comment: just don't use WeakReference, instead use EventBus from https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Does this issue always happen with your code?

Comment: Hi @Tommy - No, it's not stable. Yet with debugger attached it can be re-produced on my old Asus Z00AD within several attempts.

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce - Thanks for the hint. Yet I'd prefer to restrict usage of 3rd-party code in my project.

Comment: Then you just need to write your own event bus. ;)